# No Wireless Internet Connections Show Up!

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, ifconfig

Just got Ubuntu on another computer and I've never had this issue.  On Windows Vista, (the operating system alongside Ubuntu) The internet works fine.  But when I click on the icon in the top right, no Wireless Networks show up.  I don't know tons about Ubuntu so be detailed in your replies and tell it to me like I know nothing.  The help would much appreciated!

Output of `ifconfig`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:64:47:a6:62  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:18

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:461 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:461 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:35265 (35.2 KB)  TX bytes:35265 (35.2 KB)
```

How can I get it to connect to my Wi-fi?

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: this one? "sudo rfkill list"

Comment: No that is not the output from the script, you need to click on the link in my comment above and follow the directions, there will be a lot of output.

Comment: I know that's not the output, but I went there and couldnt figure out what to put in.

Comment: I think I put in the correct words and I got a text doc that said this:

Comment: It wont let me put in the output.  It's too long

Comment: In the answer where you ran the script is directions for putting the file on pastebin.

Comment: OH! thank you, I overlooked that.  Here:http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8191718/

Comment: so...now you have that info what do i do! this is so frustrating!

Comment: is there some sort of program I can download of the internet to fix this...or some command to type in?

Comment: I replied, if it fixes it please accept the answer so everyone will benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Reboot

Comment: When I put in the sudo thing a ton of stuff happened and then it said the linux thing at the bottom where you type stuff in...i pressed enter and it said command not found...what do i do? please help!

Comment: wait I searched the linux thing in the "app store" thing and it popped up and its now downloading...am i on the right track?

Comment: Is this what you installed from software center `linux-firmware-nonfree` if yes then it should work.

Comment: that's what i searched and 1 thing popped up: non-free firmware for linux kernel drivers.  I got that and im about to reboot.  If it works ill come back

Comment: Yes it did, enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your wireless driver. Just do the following: Connect your laptop to internet using the cable, open application called "Software & Updates", go to tab "Additional Drivers" and there select to use proprietary driver for your wireless card.

Comment: there were no drives to select...

Answer (score 0):

Your wireless network card may not have native support on Ubuntu. Firstly check if Ubuntu can detect your network card by running the command lspci or lsusb depending on whether your network card is pci/usb based. It should show something like this:

> 04:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network
>   Adapter (rev 01)

Now open the link below and check to see if your network card has support.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported

Also looking at ndiswrapper may also help as it allows Ubuntu to run Windows wireless driver

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper

Comment: Not to be a moron...but how do I know if my network card is pci or usb based???

Comment: If the network card is internal (inside your computer) then it is a PCI network card whether it be a desktop/laptop but if the network card is a USB dongle connected via a usb port then it is a usb based network card. Alternatively if you are still not sure you can just run both the commands and check the output for a network controller on the list of hardware.

Answer (score 0):

go to your terminal and type this command

```
$ gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf*
```

**update**:
add "sudo" at the beginning of the command above:

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d ......
```

then you want to find where it says:

```
#causes no end of confusion by creating unexpected network interfaces
blacklist eth[a number here]
```

and add a hashtag before the line like this:

```
#causes no end of confusion by creating unexpected network interfaces
#blacklist eth[a number here]
```

reboot your laptop, and you should be good

Comment: I tried this fix and i got as far as putting the #.  When I did it wouldn't let me save it.  It says read only...how do I get permission???

Comment: Whats your wireless card model?

Comment: Idk! how do I know that?

Comment: And how do I get permission to edit the doc and put the "#?"

Comment: OH! I SAW YOUR UPDATE.  Thank you.  So i added the sudo and it let me edit the doc but the internet STILL isn't working.  Any advice?